# Stopping and Starting systemctl Service via Cron job

Tags: linux, services, cron

So I have created a service on my Raspberry Pi 3 using the method described [here](https://www.thedigitalpictureframe.com/how-to-add-crossfading-slide-transitions-to-your-digital-picture-frame-using-pi3d/).

I can stop and start the service from a Terminal session easily enough, and the service starts at boot.

However I would like to also stop and start the service at set times, or after another event. Currently trying to do this via cron which currently looks like this:

```
# Stop picframe Everyday at 21h55
30 21 * * * pi systemctl --user stop picframe.service

# Turn off display Everyday at 22h00
35 21 * * * vcgencmd display_power 0

# Start picframe Everyday at 06h55
55 06 * * * pi systemctl --user start picframe.service

# Turn on screen Everyday at 0700
00 07 * * * vcgencmd display_power 1
```

This doesn't appear to stop and start the service when required.

Was using the suggestion [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/942905/how-can-i-stop-a-systemd-service-with-cron). However should I be using a .timer as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265704/start-stop-a-systemd-service-at-specific-times)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which crontab file are you editing?

Comment: I assume it is the one for the 'pi' user (which I am logged in as).